# TemplateSyntaxError in flask

Tags: python, web, flask

I have a flask application, with so far only one html page, with a layout.html page as a template. Here is the syntax:

```
{%extends "layout.html"}

{% block content %}

<main class="hero-section">
<div class="container">


<div class="section-content">
    <h2> Discover places near you. </h2>
    <a href="#" class="btn-primary">Sign up</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn-secondary">Learn more</a>
</div>

<div class="section-device">
    <img src="statkc/img/device.png">
</div>


 <div class="clearfix"></div>

 </div>
</main>

{% endblock %}
```

here is my template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <link href'http://fonts.googleapis.com   /css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600' rel='stylesheet'>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/main.css">

  </head>
    <body>
      <header>
           <div class="container">
              <h1 class="title"> Learning Flask </h1>
        </div>      
       </header>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

it returns an error templatesyntaxerror unexpected '}'
I can't see where it should be, that is giving an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags need to end with `%}`, not just `}`.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
```

(Note, the full error message would have told you exactly where the error is.)